# Execution problems in visual studio for Mac 2019 (NuGet packages)

Tags: c#, nuget-package, visual-studio-mac

I want to use C# in Visual Studio but I cannot execute any C# projects

And it just shows the error, which says "Failed to read NuGet.Config due to unauthorized access. Path ...." also says "you should restore the NuGet Packages before build..."

I don't know how to solve this problem, how to restoring packages.. and able to make access authorized...

[image: error message]

the image when opening the project at first, the content in the green box tells all in that error message

Actually it is not about the code, the point is I cannot do anything due to the error above.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for comments!

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong in this problem.

Actually, from the error messages it was the point that VS cannot read NuGet.Config file in NuGet Directory in .config!
And (I am not sure exactly) VS could not make NuGet directory in my .config directory due to some access problems! So I make the NuGet directory like below picture by myself and now VS successfully restore the NuGet Packages!

[image]

I took a long time at this "simple" problem. I hope the others with same problem above not to waste pretty much time like me..

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Big Sur the solution is easier. Because Visual Studio is not an Apple program you should give it full disk access in System Preferences > Security & Privacy

Comment: Also, for Mac OS Monterey creating a config file is not enough you need to provide full access as well as @Aart Spilt says.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS:  Create Nuget folder inside `.config` folder.
`.config` is a hidden folder so access then using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.
And change the permissions of the config folder by right clicking on
`.config`->Get Info